# SQL order by with case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I meet a SQL statement with ORDER BY clause, that I can not understand.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
JOIN ...
ORDER BY (
        CASE 
            WHEN versions.effective_date IS NULL THEN 
                1 
            ELSE 
                0 
        END) DESC, 
        versions.effective_date DESC, 
        versions.name DESC, 
        versions.id DESC
```

Please point me the meaning of ORDER BY clause. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Illustration:**

Supposing original data is ordered like this

```
        effective_date, effective_date, name, id

            3/1/2010        3/1/2010     ABC   1
            1/1/2010        1/1/2010     ABC   2
            2/1/2010        2/1/2010     ABC   3
              NULL            NULL       ABC   4
              NULL            NULL       ABC   5
              NULL            NULL       ABC   6
```

**After ordering will be**

```
        effective_date, effective_date, name, id

              NULL            NULL       ABC   6
              NULL            NULL       ABC   5
              NULL            NULL       ABC   4
            3/1/2010        3/1/2010     ABC   1
            2/1/2010        2/1/2010     ABC   3
            1/1/2010        1/1/2010     ABC   2
```

**Translation [how the order statement will be translated at run time]:**

```
        effective_date, effective_date, name, id

                 1            NULL       ABC   6
                 1            NULL       ABC   5
                 1            NULL       ABC   4
                 0          3/1/2010     ABC   1
                 0          2/1/2010     ABC   3
                 0          1/1/2010     ABC   2
```

Answer (score 0):

> ORDER BY (CASE WHEN versions.effective_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC

If `versions.effective_date` not available (`NULL`), those records will be **`listed at last`**. All other records (`NOT NULL`) will be shown at **`top of the list`**.

Answer (score 0):

The case clause is just an extra order by condition, every row where effective date is null has value 1, the others have value 0. The ordering happens first on that column, descending.

Answer (score 0):

It will place all rows where versions.effective_date IS NULL at the top of the list.

Basically it is dividing the result into 2 major sections

- Top section NULL effective_date
- Bottom Section NOT NULL effective_date

this `case expression` is similar to an IF() function in Excel

=IF(logical-test,value-if-true, value-if-false)

```
CASE 
    WHEN versions.effective_date IS NULL -- the logical test
    1 -- value if true
    else 0 -- value if false
END
```

Comment: It's the other way around, NULLS are at the top, because of the `DESC` after the `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your results will be ordered in this way

1. First show results when `effective_date` is null and the then show
   records who has `effective_date`
2. Secondly if records have `effective_date` date then order them in
   descending way like records with greater date will be returned
3. Thirdly within same criteria as above order records in alphabetical
   order but in descending way so the records whose name starts with z
   will be returned first
4. And lastly within same criteria as above,order records with higher
   id first